# how to insert a value in a html space box by vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to insert a specific value at 3 differents space boxes. However, I did not find a example that works with the site which I am using.

Site: http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/indices/indices-de-segmentos-e-setoriais/serie-historica-do-di.htm

```
Sub Download()

Dim user, password As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Planilha Ativa
Worksheets("Realizado").Activate

'Abrir a página da BMF
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.navigate "http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/indices/indices-de-segmentos-e-setoriais/serie-historica-do-di.htm"
    ie.Visible = True

ie.Document.all.Item("DT_DIA_DE").Value = "02"
ie.Document.all.Item("DT_MES_DE").Value = "01"
ie.Document.all.Item("DT_ANO_DE").Value = "2019"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Internet Explorer:**

It is inside an iframe. You could initially navigate direct to the src source for the iframe with

```
.Navigate2 http://estatisticas.cetip.com.br/astec/series_v05/paginas/lum_web_v05_template_informacoes_di.asp?str_Modulo=completo&int_Idioma=1&int_Titulo=6&int_NivelBD=2
```

Or, select the iframe element and navigate to its src

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub NavigateLinks()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/indices/indices-de-segmentos-e-setoriais/serie-historica-do-di.htm"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .Navigate2 .document.getElementById("bvmf_iframe").src
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .document
            .querySelector("[name='DT_DIA_DE']").Value = "02"
            .querySelector("[name='DT_MES_DE']").Value = "01"
            .querySelector("[name='DT_ANO_DE']").Value = "2018"
            .querySelector("[href*='EnvioChecaDados']").Click
        End With
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**XHR (XMLHttpRequest):**

The page does a POST form XHR request to this url:

```
http://estatisticas.cetip.com.br/astec/series_v05/paginas/lum_web_v04_10_03_consulta.asp
```

You could attempt to replicate that request and avoid a browser altogether. If you manually make the request on the page and inspect the network tab via dev tools (F12 - Chrome), you will find that url. The POST form parameters are all shown including the date parts:

[image]

---

Click download:

```
.document.querySelector(".primary-text a").click
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr!!

The lastest help: 
If I use the second example and need to download (or click the button on the up of the page), how would I do?

Item: "Clique aqui para fazer o download do arquivo .XLS"

Comment: Answer Accepted, Thx

Comment: I don't know why, but the updated that you suggested did not work if I run normally the code (using the F5). I mean if I use F8 to see the step-by-step, the code works, but the previous example not. 
And the Function Application.SendKeys "%{S}" to complete the download as well did not work. Do you have any ideia? QHarr

Comment: You need to indicate which line fails on. If works with f8 then put a pause before the line that fails e.g Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,2)

Comment: Increase the number 2 to a higher number of seconds if required.